# Reload page with anchor after submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, reload

I have a big form in PHP with several tables, each of one calculates a sum (of price and quantity) and then there's one at the end that calculates the total.
The structure is, more or less, this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="purchase_form">
    <div id="purchase_1">
        <table>
            <input id="price_1">
            <input id="quantity_1">

            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Click here to calculate the partial">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="purchase_2">
        <table>
            <input id="price_2">
            <input id="quantity_2">

            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Click here to calculate the partial">
        </table>
    </div>

    <tr>
        <td id="price_sum"><?php *script* ?></td>
        <td id="quantity_sum"><?php *script* ?></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Now, when I click on submit to calculate the "partial", it gives me the total, at the same time. I know it's not a *state-of-the-art* form, but anyway, just try to turn a blind eye on that.

What I want is, when I click on submit button, to have the page reloaded showing the form I have clicked on. Like, if I click on submit of the #purchase_1 table, I want the page to reload on #purchase_1 table, and so on.

Is it possible to do that with javascript?

Comment: If you want a form to submit to the same page you can just leave the `action` part out, just completely remove it.

Comment: Ok, and for giving like an "anchor" to the forms, have you got something in mind?